# Error connecting to MongoDB on production Vercel

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js, vercel

I have recently deployed a NextJS app to production and it's failing to connect to my database. In development mode it works just fine.

[image: I'm getting this log on Vercel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correctly set your security parameters.

For Atlas to work with Vercel you need to set Network Access > ip whitelist > *.

Comment: No I hadn't, doing that solved the problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if the problem is solved now @TomasDiMaria, comments are intended only for requesting/providing additional details.